# Angular Js screen resize without any event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make my UI responsive to screen change. I am connected to 2 different screens and drag the browser to another window.

The resize function does not work in those cases because no event is triggered. How can I resize my UI in those cases?

currently I am using the below code:

```
function getResizedDatasheetTableHeight() {
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var datasheetTableHeight = (parseInt(windowHeight) - 380);
return parseInt(datasheetTableHeight);
}
```

And I am calling this function in a get function :

```
$scope.styleDatasheetTableParentDiv = { 'height':(getResizedDatasheetTableHeight() + 52) + 'px' }

$scope.styleDatasheetTableChildDiv = { 'height':(getResizedDatasheetTableHeight() - 20) + 'px', width: '98%' }

$scope.styleDatasheetPaginatorDiv = { 'top': (getResizedDatasheetTableHeight() + 262) + 'px' }
```

I need to know how to respond to screen change.
Please help

Comment: Some kind of auto maximize, am I right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Can you help???

Comment: Automatic resizing, without and event, should detect dynamically!!!